# Why do I get same result from two difference?

Tags: javascript, html

```
       <h2>Volume</h2>

        <b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
        <input type=radio name=volConvert id="LitToGal" value="LitToGal" checked>Litre To Gallon<br>
        <input type=radio name=volConvert id="GalToLit" value="GalToLit">Gallon To Litre
        <br><br>

        <label>
            <b>Input a data: </b><br>
            <input name="volData" id="inVolData" type="text" size="10">
        </label><br><br>

        <p>
            <input type=button value="Convert" onClick="VolConvert()" />
        </P>

        <h4 id="result"></h4>

    </div>
```

var value = parseFloat(0);
var conValue = parseFloat(0);

function VolConvert() {

```
if (document.getElementById("LitToGal")) {

    var inputData = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inVolData").value);
    value = (inputData * 16.52);

} else if (document.getElementById("GalToLit")) {

    var inputData = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inVolData").value);
    value = (inputData * 113.50);
}

var conValue = value.toFixed(2);;

resultmessage = ("The converted value: " + conValue);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultmessage;
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: The condition is wrong. You should check whether the radio button is selected instead of if it exists `document.getElementById(‘LitToGal’).checked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have the following If-Statement:

```
if (document.getElementById("LitToGal")) {
    ...
else if (document.getElementById("GalToLit")) {
    ...
}
```

This `document.getElementById("LitToGal")` will always be true since the element exists in your HTML .
Meaning `value = (inputData * 16.52);` will always be the result.

To fix the statement, try the following:

```
if (document.getElementById("LitToGal").checked) {
    ...
else if (document.getElementById("GalToLit").checked) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the "checked" value

```
function VolConvert() {

if (document.getElementById("LitToGal").checked) {

    var inputData = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inVolData").value);
    value = (inputData * 16.52);

} else if (document.getElementById("GalToLit").checked) {

    var inputData = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inVolData").value);
    value = (inputData * 113.50);
}

var conValue = value.toFixed(2);;

resultmessage = ("The converted value: " + conValue);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultmessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("LitToGal").checked)
if (document.getElementById("GalToLit").checked)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.